# ENUM translation in javascript

Tags: reactjs, enums, ecmascript-6

I want to define a type translation from the enum values I get from an api and translate it to a string stored in the application.

I get `price.currentPrice.comparisonFactor = 1` from the api and I want to store this in a comparisonFactor.js typefile in my project so its easibly editable.

My attempt was to do :

```
export const comparisonTypes = {
  0: 'PerKilogram',
  1: 'PerLitre',
  2: 'PerPiece',
  3: 'PerMetre',
  4: 'PerLoad',
  5: 'PerWash',
  6: 'ReadyToDrink',
  7: 'ReadyToEat',
  8: 'DrainedWeight',
}
```

I can import this by `import comparisonTypes from 'path-to-file.js'`
But I need to be able to match it based on my int prop passed from the response. I need some help and suggestions on how to do this in best practice.

Should I do a selector that maps this object or is it possible to search the object for the matching int or even a better way? :D

Comment: `const unitLabel = comparisonTypes[yourInt]` ?

Comment: I am just dumb, I could define comparisonTypes to an array and do comparisonTypes[Prop]

Comment: Well, an object with a number as key is better as you'll be sure that at key 2 you'll have the correct value. An array could have its order changed.

Comment: True. Didnt think you could reference an object by obj[key]. Rookie :D Thanks @ChrisR

Answer (score 1):

As it can be seen in [TypeScript output](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20comparisonTypes%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PerKilogram%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PerLitre%0D%0A%7D), numeric enums provide two-way mapping. This way enum property name can be mapped to numeric value, and vice versa.

So it should be:

```
export const comparisonTypes = {
  0: 'PerKilogram',
  PerKilogram: 0,
  1: 'PerLitre',
  PerLitre: 1,
  ...
};
```

This can be rewritten as constructor function to make it DRY:

```
function Enum(...fields) {
  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    this[i] = [fields[i]];
    this[fields[i]] = i;
  }
}

const comparisonTypes = new Enum(
  'PerKilogram',
  'PerLitre',
  ...
);
```

This approach is JavaScript way. It won't work well for TypeScript because DRYness doesn't provide type safety.